# sizeof(struct foo) not constant?

Tags: c, struct, enums, sizeof, microchip

Im developing with Microchips XC8 C compiler 1.12.

I have the following code snippet but the compiler is not happy with it.

```
struct _foo {
    int a;
};

enum BAR {
    CONST1 = sizeof(struct _foo)
};
```

The error I get is: `main.c:6: error: integer expression required`
Why does it generate that error? Isn't the size of any struct in C constant?
If I use sizeof(int) everything works fine.

Note: the XC8 compiler v1.12 follows the C90 standard, not the modern C99 standard.

**PS** This does compile:

```
char abc[sizeof(struct _foo)];
```

And this expression also needs to be a compile-time constant leading me to think that this actually isn't what's going wrong in the enum declaration.

Comment: This looks like a limitation in the compiler.

Comment: @Gilles: No, a variable-length array cannot be a member of a structure. (There are flexible array members, but they don't contribute to the size reported by `sizeof`.)

Comment: Does `const int sizeof_foo = sizeof (struct _foo); enum BAR { CONST1 = sizeof_foo };` work? I wouldn't expect it to make any difference, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Identifiers starting with an underscore are reserved; you shouldn't use them in your own code. `struct foo` is a perfectly good name.

Comment: @KeithThompson as I just installed the compiler on my machine for this question, I can tell you, no it makes no difference

Comment: @KeithThompson but funny enough `const int sizeof_foo = sizeof (struct _foo);` itself does not trigger any warning at file scope, which means in a *non* enumeration context `sizeof (struct _foo)` is correctly identified as a constant expression.

Comment: As a workaround, you can always write `#define CONST1 sizeof(struct _foo)` (add a cast to `int` if you need that).

Comment: @KeithThompson I've tried that but that doesn't work either.

Comment: @BitJunky he means get rid of the `enum` declaration and just use the `define`

Comment: @KeithThompson: At file scope (like in this instance), yes, identifiers beginning with an underscore are always reserved, but they're not reserved at local scopes if the second character is not an uppercase letter or another underscore (C99 §7.1.3/1).  But it's a good rule to never use identifiers beginning with an underscore.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield I removed the underscore but unfortunately it made no difference.

Comment: @BitJunky: I didn't expect it to; avoiding identifiers starting with underscores is just good practice. (Sorry I didn't make that clear.)

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a limitation / bug of the Microchip XC8 compiler.

In a enumeration constant definition, the compiler does not  consider `sizeof (X)` as constant expression (even if actually it is in c90 or c99) when `X` is either an aggregate or union type, or an object of an aggregate type or union type.

Comment: Yes, it's a compiler limitation, but not the one you describe, since `sizeof(int)` works.

Comment: @Gilles is the cast fixing the compilation error? The compiler may make some limitation "exceptions" for the size of standard scalar types.

Comment: @Gilles I installed the compiler on my machine and indeed my previous  explanation was not the good one.